# Cordova: Cannot find module 'uuid'

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

Every time I try to run any cordova command I get this error:

```
$ cordova build --release android
Android Studio project detected
(node:26671) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Cannot find module 'uuid'
(node:26671) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm using Node v8 and NPM v5, have tried different Node/NPM versions but always get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue on my project where we had to wrap our cordova app with Cordova Micro VPN Plugin. The below command fix my issue.

```
npm install uuid
```

Let me know if it helps.